# Get value from void on Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, string, return

I want to get json string from my void method, let see

```
-(void) getIDfromMarket{}
```

I want show result json from getIDfromMarket and it already succeeds, now I want to pass it into

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

how to do that? Here's my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self getIDfromMarket];
     NSLog(@"ID==",ID);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//////get global market From JSOn
-(void) getIDfromMarket{
    NSError *error = nil;
    ///set params url to get market localization
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl"]];
    if (jsonData) {
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSArray *Market = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"market"];
        NSLog(@"%@", Market);
        if(Market==NULL){
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oh Snap!" message:@"Can't Get Market ID " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];

        }
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Error Fetch Market ID");
 }

}

@end
```

I want to log `NSLog(@"%@", Market);` not on viewDidLoad, how to do that?

Comment: Is your question about how to return a value from a method?  If you want to return something from `getIDfromMarket` then put the return type instead of `void`, `void` means no value.

Comment: hey borrden , i want to get NSLog(@"%@", Market); value show on viewDidLoad, let say NSLog value == "SOMEID" how to call it from ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Do you understand what a return value is?

Comment: If market is member variable then you can log in viewDidLoad.  or return value from -(id)getIDfromMarket;

Comment: @ParagBafna now i change -(void) getIDfromMarket{
 --> -(id)getIDfromMarket;  now how to call it into viewDidLoad??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If market is member variable then you can log in viewDidLoad. or return value from `-(id)getIDfromMarket;`

```
-(id) getIDfromMarket{
    // your code
    return market; // autorelase
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *lArray  = [self getIDfromMarket];// autorelase
    NSLog(@"ID==",lArray);

}
```

Comment: its error "use of undeclared" identifier 'market',where is should declare market? *sorry i'm noobs

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSArray *) getIDfromMarket{
    NSError *error = nil;
    ///set params url to get market localization
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl"]];
    if (jsonData) {
        id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        NSArray *Market = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"market"];
        NSLog(@"%@", Market);
        if(Market==nil){
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oh Snap!" message:@"Can't Get Market ID " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            return nil;
        } else {
            return Market;
        }
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Error Fetch Market ID");
        return nil;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use the results returned from your JSON request you should either change your getIDFromMarket return type from (void) to (NSArray) then at the end of the method if the request is successful you type "return Market" if it fails return nil.

Then from -(void) viewWillApper call the method like NSArray *thisArray = [getIDFromMarket];

From here you will be able to use what is in the array and set the data onscreen before view did load

The other option would be to have a property of NSArray and when the results are returned you would store it into this property which you could later access from any method in that class.

Hope this helps

```
//////get global market From JSOn
-(NSArray) getIDfromMarket{
    NSError *error = nil;
    ///set params url to get market localization
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl"]];
    if (jsonData) {
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSArray *Market = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"market"];
        NSLog(@"%@", Market);
        if(Market==NULL){
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oh Snap!" message:@"Can't Get Market ID " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            return nil;
        }
        else {
            return Market;
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Error Fetch Market ID");
        return nil;
 }
```

}

then in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    [super viewWillAppear];

    NSArray *results = [self getIDfromMarket];
     NSLog(@"ID==%@",results);
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, its bad practice to ask other developers to write your code for you. But were all here to help, just don't abuse it.

Comment: the function should be -(NSArray *) getIDfromMarket with the *